# Scope issue appending to string

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, scope

I am attempting to convert a CSV file using the node csvtojson library, look for certain data in the file, add the data to a string, then log the string (eventually I'll write this to a text file).

The JSON Object comes out fine and I can log the data from within the function, but I can't append it to my string using +=. I assume this is a scope issue but I am not sure where I went wrong.

```
//Converter Class
var Converter=require("csvtojson").core.Converter;

var fs=require("fs");

var capsuleFile="capsule-contacts.csv";
var capsuleFileStream=fs.createReadStream(capsuleFile);

//new csv to json converter instance
var csvConverter=new Converter({constructResult:true});

var fileToWrite = "";

csvConverter.on("end_parsed",function(jsonObj){
   for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
    if(jsonObj[i].Type == "Organisation") {
        console.log(jsonObj[i].Organisation.toString()); //this works
        fileToWrite += jsonObj[i].Organisation.toString();  
        fileToWrite += "     -     ";
        fileToWrite += jsonObj[i]["Email Address"].toString();
        fileToWrite += "     -     ";
        fileToWrite += jsonObj[i]["Work Phone"].toString();
        fileToWrite += "\n";
        console.log(fileToWrite); //this works
    }
   }

});

//this does not work
console.log(fileToWrite);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csvtojson` performs the conversion ***asynchronously***, so you cannot expect `console.log(fileToWrite);` to show the correct output because the `end_parsed` event does not happen until some time in the future, after your `console.log(fileToWrite);` has executed. Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming (and node.js).